# TypeError Invalid shape (4,) for image data on matplotlib show image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imageio

I try to convert the RGB image to greyscale using the below code

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pic = imageio.imread("my2.jpg")
gray = lambda rgb : np.dot(rgb[... , :3] , [0.299 , 0.587, 0.114]) 
gray = gray(pic)  
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap(name = 'gray'))
```

But it was an error with an error on the last row

```
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap(name = 'gray'))
```

the error is

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (4,) for image data
```

if someone can help me on this issue

they array produce by `"gray" is : Array([253.447, 249.119, 253.632,  29.07 ])`

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine (Python 3.7.12). Check if your image is a valid jpg file and perhaps try reinstalling your libraries. Check your imageio version with `imageio.__version__`.

Comment: thanks @LeonardoAraujo yeah i think some problem with my picture, thanks a lot